SpringBoot web application 404 not found error
I am learning Spring Boot and while making a web app, I encountered WhiteLabel error page with status code 404. Below is my controller code
 @Controller
public class HomeController {
    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String home(){
        System.out.println("nskjdnwmndkjnwekd wklndwkelkx");
        return "index.jsp";
    }
}


This is my project structure. HomeController class is inside the Controller folder. I also added tomcat japser dependency in the pom file but still the error is same. i tried with adding jstl dependency also but didn't work.
Update: The project is working on Mac machines but not on windows. Any idea what could have gone wrong.

Check your logs on what is giving the 404, the controller or the index. When learning Spring Boot (or any modern development) I would advice against using JSP. It has limitations in fat jars and can be a pain to get to work, instead you might want to look at something like Thymeleaf instead.

Thanks for your advice. I was following a video tutorial on YouTube and he performed these steps. Also, the same program is working in one of my known w/o even changing anything in the code.

Well I doubt you followed the actual tutorial. You either missed some steps, didn't follow the packaging or decided to do some upgrades to libraries which aren't compatible or forgot some configuration. If you follow a tutorial follow the tutorial including the versions used.

But if there is some problem with the code or configuration, it shouldn't be working in some other system. I am adding the github link to this repo. You can try. https://github.com/love231992/SpringBootMVC

I'm not going to try but from the looks of your pom you aren't following the tutorial, as you are including an incompatible JSTL version.

The tutorial didn't use the JSTL dependency. I added it later after seeing some solutions on stackoverflow for this problem. Currently I have v3 jstl and still not working

Well you still didn't explain what gives the 404, the page or the URL. If it works on one not the other machine, check the JDK. OS could be different. Nonetheless I wouldn't suggest a tutorial with JSP in the first place.

jdk is same on both machines but yes os is different. so can i replace jsp with html. will it work ?

For an update, I tried with html file which i placed at src/main/resources/static and it got rendered perfectly but jsp file is still not working.

update your controller as follows, see if this makes the difference
> @RestController 
> public class HomeController {
>  @GetMapping("/")
>     public String home() {
>         System.out.println("nskjdnwmndkjnwekd wklndwkelkx");
>         return "index";
>     } }


In Spring Boot, by default, the src/main/resources/static directory is used to serve static content. If you want to serve JSP files, you need to configure a ViewResolver to resolve the JSP files correctly.
Add the spring-boot-starter-tomcat dependency to your pom.xml file if you haven't already:
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

Add the spring-boot-starter-web dependency if you haven't already:
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>

Configure a ViewResolver bean in your @Configuration class:
@Configuration
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void configureViewResolvers(ViewResolverRegistry registry) {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        registry.viewResolver(resolver);
    }
}

Move your index.jsp file to src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views/ directory.
Modify your controller to return just the name of the JSP file without the extension:
@Controller
public class HomeController {
    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String home() {
        System.out.println("nskjdnwmndkjnwekd wklndwkelkx");
        return "index";
    }
}


You can just specify the spring.mvc.view.prefix and suffix. No need to explicitly add a view resolver.

I tried using suffix and prefix but issue is still not resolved. Even when index.jsp was in src/main/webapp location, the app is running in my known laptop but not in mine.

@A RAM spring boot starter web dependency is already there and tomcat dependency is not required,only tomcat jasper is required which I already have.
